# Django alongside existing website possible?

Tags: django

I am considering making my website with Django. But I do already have a web app made with AngularJS online on my server with a few users every day and I don't want to take it down.

So is there a way to exclude some paths from being processed by Django?
Even better, during my development phase, is it possible to run Django only in a sub directory? I mean `website.com` would not be processed by Django and for example `website.com/django/*` would be.

This way I could become familiar with the deployment process without having to take down my current website.

**Is it possible? What are my options?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, it depends entirely on the webserver you are going to use so I can't give you a general tutorial.

Using the currently documented method of deploying Django with `mod_wsgi` (personally I'd recommend using Gunicorn with Nginx) you can follow this tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

The only change you are going to have to make is the `WSGIScriptAlias /...` line:

In your case it would be something like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /django/ /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Great that is a big relief ! I can start coding with a peaceful mind ;) 
That would be for installing django in a django folder right? And what about excluding some specific paths? Let's say: `mysite.com/wabapps/*`

Comment: @MathieuDavid _"installing django in a django folder"_ tells me you need to read the tutorial - it will make things clear.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I know you don't literally install Django in that folder. But I found no better way to say it. So what I wanted to say is: *configure Django in a way that every url that does not match `mysite.com/django/*` bypasses Django and works like it used to before I installed Django* 

I am new to Django but I did some research though ;) But I have to admit, the deployment process and server configuration still is a little sketchy for me.